# Fullcalendar not syncing with Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have the following code to sync my google calendar with jquery fullcalendar but it's not pulling in any information.

Anyone got any idea why?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/tom.brennand%40gmail.com/public/basic"
    }
});
```

Comment: permissions? It should be a public calendar I guess

Comment: Add that as an answer and I'll give you the tick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try on:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 eventSources: [
            {
                url: 'yourUrl',
                className: 'gcal-event',
                color: '#3a87ad'
            }
        ]
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was permissions in the calendar - as stated by [emilioicai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3265176/emilioicai)